# I'm unable to view the original image on the button

Tags: html, css

This url has the image that to be displayed on button

http://s28.postimg.org/7zvdncg71/buttonbg.png

CSS

```
.button1{
            background-image: url(http://s28.postimg.org/7zvdncg71/buttonbg.png);           
            position: absolute; 
            height: 50px; 
            width: 210px;
            top: 60px;
            left: 500px;
        }
```

HTML

```
<button class="button1" type="button" >
```

When you open the link it is different, and on button the image is different.
Please help me how to view the original image on button.

Comment: Do you need to use a `button` tag? You could change it to an `a` tag and style it to use that image, or just use the glass icon, and set the background using CSS

Comment: Don't use a background image. `<button><img src="" alt=""></button>`

Comment: The image is too big for the button. You will only see the top-left blue corner inside the button; unless you scale the background image somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a few more styles:

```
.button1 {
    background-image: url(http://s28.postimg.org/7zvdncg71/buttonbg.png);
    background-color: #3CB1DE;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 210px;
    top: 60px;
    left: 500px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z21pheqr/

Comment: Thank you, its working. By the way, why is that background-color for an image?

Comment: Try removing it, you'll know. The image has been asked to "contain" itself in the button. That means, unless the image size is exactly the same as the button size, the button background is going to expose itself (left and right if the height of image > height of button and top and bottom if the width of the image > width of the button). To avoid this, the `background-color` is set to the `background-color` of the image. An alternative would be to set `background-size: cover`. But that'd make your magnifier image go out of the button area.

Answer (score 1):

at first you need quotes in url

`background-image: url('http://s28.postimg.org/7zvdncg71/buttonbg.png');`

second is that your image is larger than your button. try

```
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

and 
    `height: 85px;`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rn5ox2a/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
.button1{
        background-image: url(http://s28.postimg.org/7zvdncg71/buttonbg.png);   
        position: absolute;
        background-size:cover;
        height: 84px; 
        width: 210px;
        top: 60px;
        left: 500px;
    }
```